# Using mouseDown in selenium with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am using the selenium ice to export the test to ruby and everything is working except for the mouseDown and mouseUp. Did I write the code correctly or is the exported version not the correct way of doing it.

```
@driver.get "https://sample-website.com/"
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@name='username']").send_keys "username"
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@name='password']").send_keys "password"
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[@name='submit']").mouseDown
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[@name='submit']").mouseUp
```

the error is

NoMethodError: undefined method `mouseDown' for #Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x007fa228b43418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to replace the `mouseDown` and `mouseUp` with one line:

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//button[@name='submit']").click
```